# Unable to get slug from my Laravel 8 database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, blogs

I'm putting together a blog with Laravel 8.  I can create the posts, categories, subcategories, and sub-subcategories with no problem.  The problem is when I try to display a blog post with the slug instead of the id.  I get the following error.

> Missing required parameter for [Route: mainblogs.show] [URI: natural-hair-blogs/d/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug].

**Controller**

```
public function MainBlogShow($slug)
{
    $blog = HairBlog::whereSlug($slug)->first();
    
    return view('natural-hair-blogs.show', compact('blog'));
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/natural-hair-blogs/d/{slug}', 
    [HairBlogController::class, 'MainBlogShow'])->name('mainblogs.show');
```

**Blade/View**

```
{{ route('mainblogs.show', [$blog->slug]) }}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

Comment: try `route('mainblogs.show', ['slug' => $blog->slug])`

Comment: No dice.  It spits out the same error

Comment: `route('mainblogs.show', ['slug' => $blog->slug])` is the answer. You may need to `artisan route:clear`

Comment: Does your blog have a slug? Double check you don't use this route somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes it has a slug, but it keeps getting the same missing slug error.  I've tried clearing the cache, and made sure to pass the slug first with the whereSlug() function.  My route reads  Route::get('/natural-hair-blogs/d/{slug}'.  This is beyond strange.

Comment: When I use {{ URL::to('/natural-hair-blogs/d').'/'.$blog->id.'/'.$blog->slug }} it works.

Comment: Route parameters can be passed many ways. What you're doing is fine, as is the suggestion, and as is `route('mainblogs.show', $blog->slug);`. Clear your caches with `artisan optimize:clear` to ensure your view or route isn't cached. BTW you can simplify your controller code using route model binding. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding